# How long can someone keep my server?

Tags: civil-law

Ex employer has a server with their website and archive on it. I bought that server and have receipts. Employer claims they need time to wipe their info from my server. It's been a month already, and employer is still asking for more time. How should I go about getting the server back? USA, DC.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they have some contractual basis for detaining the server that supersedes common law standards, then: After making a clear demand for return, file (probably in small claims court) for relief under the common law principles of [detinue or replevin](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/24425/10).